# html menu overwriting another dropdown

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

I'm adding a notifications dropdown to my menu which is createn in a partial view (we're working with razor so it's a cshtml file)

this is the fragment where i create the two dropdowns

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <button id="menuNotifList" class="btn dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-themed btnDrop fal fa-bell" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"></button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" x-placement="top-start">
            <partial name="_DropdownNotification" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
        <button id="menuDropCuenta" class="btn dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-themed btnDrop" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">
            Cuenta
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-cuenta" x-placement="top-start">
            <partial name="_DropdownAccount" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

and it's displayed this way (the *See all notifications* link is inside the partial _DropdownNotifications)
[image]

my problem is, that the moment I click the *See all notifications* link, it's texts overwirtes teh text of the dropdown next to it
[image]

any idea what could be causing this issue? I can afford to make any changes to the second dropdown (the one with id="menuDropCuenta") because i use its values to basically everything inside the site.

EDIT:

This issue does not happens if I switch the positions and send the notifications dropdown AFTER the other drop BUT the client specifically wants it in the troublesome order, so just switching them is also not a solution.

Comment: If the both the dropdowns has same id (can happen if you have copied and pasted the code) then this issue might occur. Check the ids of both of them.

Comment: the buttons have different ids menuDropCuenta and menuNotifList.